# Bootstrap 4 - Javascript textbox keyup event firing only once and not working next time

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

Having 4 dropdowns with search textbox inbuilt on each. Added keyup event on all the search textboxes of dropdowns. This keyup event is working fine after document load as expected but when selecting an item in dropdown, the trigger works in a such a way that it will populate the other dropdowns based on selected value. So after the cascading effect of when selection on dropdown populating the other 3 dropdowns, keyup event is not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ProductCategory").multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Choose',
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            //alert('Hide event invoked!');
            var productcategory = $("#ProductCategory").val();
            alert(productcategory);
            //$('#ProductCategory').multiselect('rebuild');

            if (productcategory != null && productcategory != "") {
        var ReportHeading = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ReportHeading"]));
        //For Selection Filter Partial View
        $(".filter-loader").css("display", "block");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("OnChangeProductCategory", "SalesByCustomer")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'PC': '' + productcategory + '', 'RH': '' + ReportHeading +'' },
            datatype: "text",
            async: true,
            contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                var json_objbr = $.parseJSON(data.branddata);

                var brli = [];
                jQuery.each(json_objbr, function (i, item) {
                    brli.push({
                        'label': item,
                        'value': item,
                        'selected':true
                    })
                });

                //alert(brli);
                $('#Brand').multiselect('dataprovider', brli);


                var json_objItm = $.parseJSON(data.itemdata);

                var Itmli = [];
                jQuery.each(json_objItm, function (i, item) {
                    Itmli.push({
                        'label': item["ItemCodeandDesc"],
                        'value': item["ItemCode"],
                        'selected': true
                    })
                });

                $('#Item').multiselect('dataprovider', Itmli);


                var json_objSrp = $.parseJSON(data.salesrepdata);

                var Srpli = [];
                jQuery.each(json_objSrp, function (i, item) {
                    Srpli.push({
                        'label': item,
                        'value': item,
                        'selected': true
                    })
                });
                $('#SalesRep').multiselect('dataprovider', Srpli);


                $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Unable to Connect Server');
                $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
            }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $("#Brand").multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Choose',
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            //alert('Hide event invoked!');
           var brand = $("#Brand").val();
     if (brand != null && brand != "") {
         var ReportHeading = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ReportHeading"]));
         $(".filter-loader").css("display", "block");
         //For Selection Filter Partial View
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("OnChangeBrand", "SalesByCustomer")',
             type: "POST",
             data: { 'Br': '' + brand + '', 'RH': '' + ReportHeading + '' },
             datatype: "text",
             async: true,
             contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             success: function (data) {
                 var json_objpc = $.parseJSON(data.pcdata);

                 var pcli = "";
                 for (var i in json_objpc) {
                     pcli += '<option value="' + json_objpc[i] + '" selected>' + json_objpc[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#ProductCategory').find('option').remove();
                 $('#ProductCategory').append(pcli);
                 $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objItm = $.parseJSON(data.itemdata);

                 var Itmli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objItm) {
                     Itmli += '<option value="' + json_objItm[i].ItemCode + '" selected>' + json_objItm[i].ItemCodeandDesc + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#Item').find('option').remove();
                 $('#Item').append(Itmli);
                 $('#Item').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objSrp = $.parseJSON(data.salesrepdata);

                 var Srpli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objSrp) {
                     Srpli += '<option value="' + json_objSrp[i] + '" selected>' + json_objSrp[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#SalesRep').find('option').remove();
                 $('#SalesRep').append(Srpli);
                 $('#SalesRep').multiselect('rebuild');
                 //$("#BindFilter").html(data);
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert('Unable to Connect Server');
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             }
         });
     }
        }
    });

    $("#Item").multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Choose',
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            //alert('Hide event invoked!');
           var item = $("#Item").val();
     if (item != null && item != "") {
         var ReportHeading = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ReportHeading"]));
         $(".filter-loader").css("display", "block");
         //For Selection Filter Partial View
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("OnChangeItem", "SalesByCustomer")',
             type: "POST",
             data: { 'Itm': '' + item + '', 'RH': '' + ReportHeading + '' },
             datatype: "text",
             async: true,
             contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             success: function (data) {
                 //alert(data);
                 var json_objpc = $.parseJSON(data.pcdata);

                 var pcli = "";
                 for (var i in json_objpc) {
                     pcli += '<option value="' + json_objpc[i] + '" selected>' + json_objpc[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#ProductCategory').find('option').remove();
                 $('#ProductCategory').append(pcli);
                 $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objbr = $.parseJSON(data.branddata);

                 var brli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objbr) {
                     brli += '<option value="' + json_objbr[i] + '" selected>' + json_objbr[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#Brand').find('option').remove();
                 $('#Brand').append(brli);
                 $('#Brand').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objSrp = $.parseJSON(data.salesrepdata);

                 var Srpli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objSrp) {
                     Srpli += '<option value="' + json_objSrp[i] + '" selected>' + json_objSrp[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#SalesRep').find('option').remove();
                 $('#SalesRep').append(Srpli);
                 $('#SalesRep').multiselect('rebuild');
                 //$("#BindFilter").html(data);
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert('Unable to Connect Server');
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             }
         });
     }
        }
    });

    $("#SalesRep").multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Choose',
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            //alert('Hide event invoked!');

            var salesrep = $("#SalesRep").val();
     if (salesrep != null && salesrep != "") {
         var ReportHeading = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ReportHeading"]));
         $(".filter-loader").css("display", "block");
         //For Selection Filter Partial View
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("OnChangeSalesRep", "SalesByCustomer")',
             type: "POST",
             data: { 'Srp': '' + salesrep + '', 'RH': '' + ReportHeading + '' },
             datatype: "text",
             async: true,
             contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             success: function (data) {
                 //alert(data);
                 var json_objpc = $.parseJSON(data.pcdata);

                 var pcli = "";
                 for (var i in json_objpc) {
                     pcli += '<option value="' + json_objpc[i] + '" selected>' + json_objpc[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#ProductCategory').find('option').remove();
                 $('#ProductCategory').append(pcli);
                 $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objbr = $.parseJSON(data.branddata);

                 var brli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objbr) {
                     brli += '<option value="' + json_objbr[i] + '" selected>' + json_objbr[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#Brand').find('option').remove();
                 $('#Brand').append(brli);
                 $('#Brand').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objItm = $.parseJSON(data.itemdata);

                 var Itmli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objItm) {
                     Itmli += '<option value="' + json_objItm[i].ItemCode + '" selected>' + json_objItm[i].ItemCodeandDesc + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#Item').find('option').remove();
                 $('#Item').append(Itmli);
                 $('#Item').multiselect('rebuild');
                 //$("#BindFilter").html(data);
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert('Unable to Connect Server');
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             }
         });
     }
        }
    });


    $("#DeselectCategoryOptions").find('.multiselect-search').keyup(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        var allSelectedCat = $("#ProductCategory option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
        //alert(str);
        if (allSelectedCat == true) {
            DeselectCategoryFilter(str);
        }

    });

    $("#DeselectBrandOptions").find('.multiselect-search').keyup(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        alert(str);
        var allSelectedBra = $("#Brand option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
        if (allSelectedBra == true) {
            DeselectBrandFilter(str);
        }


    });

    $("#DeselectItemOptions").find('.multiselect-search').keyup(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        var allSelectedItem = $("#Item option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
        if (allSelectedItem == true) {
            DeselectItemFilter(str);
        }

    });

    $("#DeselectSalesRepOptions").find('.multiselect-search').keyup(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        var allSelectedSalesRep = $("#SalesRep option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
        if (allSelectedSalesRep == true) {
            DeselectSalesRepFilter(str);
        }

    });
        //alert(ReportHeading);
});

function DeselectCategoryFilter(str) {
    @*var PCArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ProductCategory"]));
    //alert(PCArray);
    for (i = 0; i < PCArray.length; i++) {
        //alert(PCArray[i]);
        $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('deselect', PCArray[i]);
    }*@
    $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('deselectAll', true);
    $("#DeselectCategoryOptions").find('.multiselect-search').focus();
    $("#DeselectCategoryOptions").find('.multiselect-search').val(str);
}

function DeselectBrandFilter(str) {
    @*var BrArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["Brand"]));
    //alert(BrArray);
    for (i = 0; i < BrArray.length; i++) {
        $('#Brand').multiselect('deselect', BrArray[i]);
    }*@
    $('#Brand').multiselect('deselectAll', true);
    $("#DeselectBrandOptions").find('.multiselect-search').focus();
    $("#DeselectBrandOptions").find('.multiselect-search').val(str);
}

function DeselectItemFilter(str) {
    @*var BrArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["Brand"]));
    //alert(BrArray);
    for (i = 0; i < BrArray.length; i++) {
        $('#Brand').multiselect('deselect', BrArray[i]);
    }*@
    $('#Item').multiselect('deselectAll', true);
    $("#DeselectItemOptions").find('.multiselect-search').focus();
    $("#DeselectItemOptions").find('.multiselect-search').val(str);
}

function DeselectSalesRepFilter(str) {
    @*var BrArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["Brand"]));
    //alert(BrArray);
    for (i = 0; i < BrArray.length; i++) {
        $('#Brand').multiselect('deselect', BrArray[i]);
    }*@
    $('#SalesRep').multiselect('deselectAll', true);
    $("#DeselectSalesRepOptions").find('.multiselect-search').focus();
    $("#DeselectSalesRepOptions").find('.multiselect-search').val(str);
}


//leftside filter click script
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.filter-close').click(function (e) {
        $('.left-wrapper').removeClass('slide');
        $('.logout-li li').removeClass('active');
        //e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

UPDATE:

What ive tried are:

1. Moved the keyup listener event outside of document.ready.
2. Moved the keyup listener after loading the options dropdown.

Both scenarios, keyup event didnt trigger.

Comment: Have added the code sample

Answer (score 0):

Could it be so the textbox is replaced in your DOM afterwards so the listener is listeneng to an element that doesn't exist anymore?

It would be easier if there is some code to look over...

edit: sorry this should be a comment but i can't comment... i can't even upvote...

Comment: Yes, I couldnt view the textbox in page source but can be seen when inspecting element via developer console.

Comment: Ok, if i see that correctly: 
You replace the selections with a request and set a listener on them?

if it is so, you need to set the listeners, every time the request changed the options

Comment: Thanks for input. Updated the post. It didnt get fire. How to check the object has event attached to it?

Comment: Well... i think there is no real way to check if an object has a listener.
The only way ist to check if it triggers.
But as you say, it doesn't trigger... have you tried to add a new Listener every time the request is successfull (at the end of it, when everything is done)?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your keyup functions outside the **document.ready()** .

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ProductCategory").multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Choose',
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            //alert('Hide event invoked!');
            var productcategory = $("#ProductCategory").val();
            alert(productcategory);
            //$('#ProductCategory').multiselect('rebuild');

            if (productcategory != null && productcategory != "") {
        var ReportHeading = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ReportHeading"]));
        //For Selection Filter Partial View
        $(".filter-loader").css("display", "block");
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("OnChangeProductCategory", "SalesByCustomer")',
            type: "POST",
            data: { 'PC': '' + productcategory + '', 'RH': '' + ReportHeading +'' },
            datatype: "text",
            async: true,
            contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                var json_objbr = $.parseJSON(data.branddata);

                var brli = [];
                jQuery.each(json_objbr, function (i, item) {
                    brli.push({
                        'label': item,
                        'value': item,
                        'selected':true
                    })
                });

                //alert(brli);
                $('#Brand').multiselect('dataprovider', brli);


                var json_objItm = $.parseJSON(data.itemdata);

                var Itmli = [];
                jQuery.each(json_objItm, function (i, item) {
                    Itmli.push({
                        'label': item["ItemCodeandDesc"],
                        'value': item["ItemCode"],
                        'selected': true
                    })
                });

                $('#Item').multiselect('dataprovider', Itmli);


                var json_objSrp = $.parseJSON(data.salesrepdata);

                var Srpli = [];
                jQuery.each(json_objSrp, function (i, item) {
                    Srpli.push({
                        'label': item,
                        'value': item,
                        'selected': true
                    })
                });
                $('#SalesRep').multiselect('dataprovider', Srpli);


                $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert('Unable to Connect Server');
                $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
            }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    $("#Brand").multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Choose',
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            //alert('Hide event invoked!');
           var brand = $("#Brand").val();
     if (brand != null && brand != "") {
         var ReportHeading = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ReportHeading"]));
         $(".filter-loader").css("display", "block");
         //For Selection Filter Partial View
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("OnChangeBrand", "SalesByCustomer")',
             type: "POST",
             data: { 'Br': '' + brand + '', 'RH': '' + ReportHeading + '' },
             datatype: "text",
             async: true,
             contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             success: function (data) {
                 var json_objpc = $.parseJSON(data.pcdata);

                 var pcli = "";
                 for (var i in json_objpc) {
                     pcli += '<option value="' + json_objpc[i] + '" selected>' + json_objpc[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#ProductCategory').find('option').remove();
                 $('#ProductCategory').append(pcli);
                 $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objItm = $.parseJSON(data.itemdata);

                 var Itmli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objItm) {
                     Itmli += '<option value="' + json_objItm[i].ItemCode + '" selected>' + json_objItm[i].ItemCodeandDesc + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#Item').find('option').remove();
                 $('#Item').append(Itmli);
                 $('#Item').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objSrp = $.parseJSON(data.salesrepdata);

                 var Srpli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objSrp) {
                     Srpli += '<option value="' + json_objSrp[i] + '" selected>' + json_objSrp[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#SalesRep').find('option').remove();
                 $('#SalesRep').append(Srpli);
                 $('#SalesRep').multiselect('rebuild');
                 //$("#BindFilter").html(data);
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert('Unable to Connect Server');
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             }
         });
     }
        }
    });

    $("#Item").multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Choose',
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            //alert('Hide event invoked!');
           var item = $("#Item").val();
     if (item != null && item != "") {
         var ReportHeading = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ReportHeading"]));
         $(".filter-loader").css("display", "block");
         //For Selection Filter Partial View
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("OnChangeItem", "SalesByCustomer")',
             type: "POST",
             data: { 'Itm': '' + item + '', 'RH': '' + ReportHeading + '' },
             datatype: "text",
             async: true,
             contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             success: function (data) {
                 //alert(data);
                 var json_objpc = $.parseJSON(data.pcdata);

                 var pcli = "";
                 for (var i in json_objpc) {
                     pcli += '<option value="' + json_objpc[i] + '" selected>' + json_objpc[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#ProductCategory').find('option').remove();
                 $('#ProductCategory').append(pcli);
                 $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objbr = $.parseJSON(data.branddata);

                 var brli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objbr) {
                     brli += '<option value="' + json_objbr[i] + '" selected>' + json_objbr[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#Brand').find('option').remove();
                 $('#Brand').append(brli);
                 $('#Brand').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objSrp = $.parseJSON(data.salesrepdata);

                 var Srpli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objSrp) {
                     Srpli += '<option value="' + json_objSrp[i] + '" selected>' + json_objSrp[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#SalesRep').find('option').remove();
                 $('#SalesRep').append(Srpli);
                 $('#SalesRep').multiselect('rebuild');
                 //$("#BindFilter").html(data);
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert('Unable to Connect Server');
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             }
         });
     }
        }
    });

    $("#SalesRep").multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '100%',
        includeSelectAllOption: true,
        enableFiltering: true,
        enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
        nonSelectedText: 'Choose',
        onDropdownHide: function (event) {
            //alert('Hide event invoked!');

            var salesrep = $("#SalesRep").val();
     if (salesrep != null && salesrep != "") {
         var ReportHeading = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ReportHeading"]));
         $(".filter-loader").css("display", "block");
         //For Selection Filter Partial View
         $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("OnChangeSalesRep", "SalesByCustomer")',
             type: "POST",
             data: { 'Srp': '' + salesrep + '', 'RH': '' + ReportHeading + '' },
             datatype: "text",
             async: true,
             contenttype: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
             success: function (data) {
                 //alert(data);
                 var json_objpc = $.parseJSON(data.pcdata);

                 var pcli = "";
                 for (var i in json_objpc) {
                     pcli += '<option value="' + json_objpc[i] + '" selected>' + json_objpc[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#ProductCategory').find('option').remove();
                 $('#ProductCategory').append(pcli);
                 $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objbr = $.parseJSON(data.branddata);

                 var brli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objbr) {
                     brli += '<option value="' + json_objbr[i] + '" selected>' + json_objbr[i] + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#Brand').find('option').remove();
                 $('#Brand').append(brli);
                 $('#Brand').multiselect('rebuild');

                 var json_objItm = $.parseJSON(data.itemdata);

                 var Itmli = "";

                 for (var i in json_objItm) {
                     Itmli += '<option value="' + json_objItm[i].ItemCode + '" selected>' + json_objItm[i].ItemCodeandDesc + '</option>';
                 }
                 $('#Item').find('option').remove();
                 $('#Item').append(Itmli);
                 $('#Item').multiselect('rebuild');
                 //$("#BindFilter").html(data);
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             },
             error: function (xhr) {
                 alert('Unable to Connect Server');
                 $(".filter-loader").css("display", "none");
             }
         });
     }
        }
    });


});

    $("#DeselectCategoryOptions").find('.multiselect-search').keyup(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        var allSelectedCat = $("#ProductCategory option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
        //alert(str);
        if (allSelectedCat == true) {
            DeselectCategoryFilter(str);
        }

    });

    $("#DeselectBrandOptions").find('.multiselect-search').keyup(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        alert(str);
        var allSelectedBra = $("#Brand option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
        if (allSelectedBra == true) {
            DeselectBrandFilter(str);
        }


    });

    $("#DeselectItemOptions").find('.multiselect-search').keyup(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        var allSelectedItem = $("#Item option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
        if (allSelectedItem == true) {
            DeselectItemFilter(str);
        }

    });

    $("#DeselectSalesRepOptions").find('.multiselect-search').keyup(function () {
        var str = $(this).val();
        var allSelectedSalesRep = $("#SalesRep option:not(:selected)").length == 0;
        if (allSelectedSalesRep == true) {
            DeselectSalesRepFilter(str);
        }

    });
        //alert(ReportHeading);


function DeselectCategoryFilter(str) {
    @*var PCArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["ProductCategory"]));
    //alert(PCArray);
    for (i = 0; i < PCArray.length; i++) {
        //alert(PCArray[i]);
        $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('deselect', PCArray[i]);
    }*@
    $('#ProductCategory').multiselect('deselectAll', true);
    $("#DeselectCategoryOptions").find('.multiselect-search').focus();
    $("#DeselectCategoryOptions").find('.multiselect-search').val(str);
}

function DeselectBrandFilter(str) {
    @*var BrArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["Brand"]));
    //alert(BrArray);
    for (i = 0; i < BrArray.length; i++) {
        $('#Brand').multiselect('deselect', BrArray[i]);
    }*@
    $('#Brand').multiselect('deselectAll', true);
    $("#DeselectBrandOptions").find('.multiselect-search').focus();
    $("#DeselectBrandOptions").find('.multiselect-search').val(str);
}

function DeselectItemFilter(str) {
    @*var BrArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["Brand"]));
    //alert(BrArray);
    for (i = 0; i < BrArray.length; i++) {
        $('#Brand').multiselect('deselect', BrArray[i]);
    }*@
    $('#Item').multiselect('deselectAll', true);
    $("#DeselectItemOptions").find('.multiselect-search').focus();
    $("#DeselectItemOptions").find('.multiselect-search').val(str);
}

function DeselectSalesRepFilter(str) {
    @*var BrArray = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(ViewData["Brand"]));
    //alert(BrArray);
    for (i = 0; i < BrArray.length; i++) {
        $('#Brand').multiselect('deselect', BrArray[i]);
    }*@
    $('#SalesRep').multiselect('deselectAll', true);
    $("#DeselectSalesRepOptions").find('.multiselect-search').focus();
    $("#DeselectSalesRepOptions").find('.multiselect-search').val(str);
}


//leftside filter click script
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.filter-close').click(function (e) {
        $('.left-wrapper').removeClass('slide');
        $('.logout-li li').removeClass('active');
        //e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for input. Updated the post. It didnt get fire. How to check if the object has event attached or not attached? Unable to run your code snippet.

Comment: $("#id").unbind('click'); unbind like this